# ReferenceError: $ is not defined $("form").validate({

Tags: jquery, error-handling, referenceerror

```
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-2.1.4.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery.validate/1.11.1/jquery.validate.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<script type="text/javascript">

$("form").validate({
    showErrors: function(errorMap, errorList) {
        // Clean up any tooltips for valid elements
        $.each(this.validElements(), function (index, element) {
            var $element = $(element);
            $element.data("title", "") // Clear the title - there is no error associated anymore
                    .removeClass("error")
                    .tooltip("destroy");
        });

        // Create new tooltips for invalid elements
        $.each(errorList, function (index, error) {
            var $element = $(error.element);
            $element.tooltip("destroy") // Destroy any pre-existing tooltip so we can repopulate with new tooltip content
                    .data("title", error.message)
                    .addClass("error")
                    .tooltip({ placement: 'right'}); // Create a new tooltip based on the error messsage we just set in the title
        });
    },

});

</script>
```

I have added these headers.But im getting error referenceError $ not defined.I have tried various possible ways. still im getting this error what to do?

Comment: Perhaps your plugins not getting loaded properly. You can check that in firebug. If possible provide your js code.

Comment: Are your script tags *before* the line you get the error on?

Comment: Yeah script tags are before that line

Comment: please add your HTML too, so that we can better suggest the answer.

Comment: I have added my js code

Comment: use `$("document").ready({});` to wrap the code

Comment: jQuery has not loaded properly or there is a conflict

Comment: make sure validate.js and and jquery-2.1.4.js  work hand-in-hand try using lesser version of jQuery or better to include jquerymigrate

include the following line in your head tag `<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-migrate/1.3.0/jquery-migrate.min.js"></script>'

Answer (score -1):

I suggest two thing,

- add document ready
- add id to the form and change the selector of the `$("form")` to `$("form#my_form")`.

  $("document").ready(function() {
      $("form#myform").validate({

  ```
    showErrors: function(errorMap, errorList) {
      // Clean up any tooltips for valid elements
      $.each(this.validElements(), function(index, element) {
        var $element = $(element);
        $element.data("title", "") // Clear the title - there is no error associated anymore
          .removeClass("error")
          .tooltip("destroy");
      });
      // Create new tooltips for invalid elements
      $.each(errorList, function(index, error) {
        var $element = $(error.element);
        $element.tooltip("destroy") // Destroy any pre-existing tooltip so we can repopulate with new tooltip content
          .data("title", error.message)
          .addClass("error")
          .tooltip({
            placement: 'right'
          }); // Create a new tooltip based on the error messsage we just set in the title
      });
    },

  });
  ```

  });

This should work then.

Thanks

Comment: Hi thanks ..but now its showing error SyntaxError: missing formal parameter

Comment: @RamyaSelvaraj can you use the code which i have modified just now, it should work.

Comment: @RamyaSelvaraj does the new code works for you? as i checked in my local system it is working now without any warning and errors.